# Vertically aligning a header element and button toolbar in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, vertical-alignment

I'm using a Bootstrap 3 button toolbar in my page and am running into an issue with vertically aligning the button toolbar and the label for the buttons- they appear to be "bottom aligned" but I'd prefer them to be vertically centered.

```
<div id="share-privacy-selector">
  <label>Sharing:</label>
  <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" style="display: inline-block;">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Public</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Hidden</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Private</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This produces the following:

[image: Elements are misaligned]

[Here's a jsBin](https://jsbin.com/vahixebalo/edit?html,output) with Bootstrap included so you can see the issue.

Should I use some element besides a  for my label? If not, what kind of styling can I add to the label, the parent div, or the div.btn-toolbar so that everything is vertically aligned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `vertical-align: bottom` on both the `label` and the `toolbar`.

**The code** to add to your jsBin:

```
#share-privacy-selector > .btn-toolbar,
#share-privacy-selector > label {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

**TIP**: Normally it would be `vertical-align: middle`, but in your case it positions the `label` higher than the `toolbar`.

**Check out the snippet**:

```css
#share-privacy-selector > .btn-toolbar,
#share-privacy-selector > label {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div id="share-privacy-selector">
  <label>Sharing:</label>
  <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" style="display: inline-block;">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Public</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Hidden</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Private</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your display rule from `block` to `table-cell` and apply `vertical-align:middle`.

Working example:

```css
#share-privacy-selector label,
#share-privacy-selector .btn-toolbar {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="share-privacy-selector">
  <label>Sharing:</label>
  <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Public</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Hidden</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Private</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```